# TypeError in circular object in javascript

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express

While fetching data by an API to get all users from database I get an error of :

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'MongoClient'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'client' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\LetsChat App\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1150:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\LetsChat App\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:271:14)
    at C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\LetsChat App\backend\controllers\authcontrollers.js:71:9
    at asyncUtilWrap (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\LetsChat App\node_modules\express-async-handler\index.js:3:20)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\LetsChat App\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\LetsChat App\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\LetsChat App\backend\middleware\authentication.js:15:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The Code for the API is :

```
  exports.getallusers = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const keyword = req.query.search ?
        {
            $or: [
                { name: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: "i" } },
                { email: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: "i" } }
            ]
        } :
        {}
    const users = USER.find(keyword).find({ _id: { $ne: req.user._id } });
    res.json({
        users
    })
})
```

Please tell me what is the problem and how should I resolve this...

Answer (score 0):

Because you return Mongo query promise as part of the response.
Try to change the code to:

```js
  exports.getallusers = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const query = { 
       _id: { $ne: req.user._id }
    };
    if ( req.query.search ) {
      query[ '$or' ] = [
         { name: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: "i" } },
         { email: { $regex: req.query.search, $options: "i" } }
      ];
    }
    const users = await USER.find(query);
    res.json({ users });
})
```